# How to show div only when content is available with fixed height?

Tags: css, html

I am showing some error messages inside a div. By default the div should be hidden and only it should be shown when there is any error content available with a fixed scrollable height (only vertical scroll).

I need to do this only using CSS. Also, this error messages are coming from asp.net validationsummary control dynamically when clicking a button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: give us some markup, what is your output in asp.net?

Comment: When I click the submit button it validates all validation controls in the asp.net form and displays the validation summary on top of the page and my issue is the page is getting bigger (I mean scrolling down if there is more error) and I want to restrict the same by wrapping the error messages around a div. See the error messages for example: We're sorry. We need the following information...
Please enter the name
Please enter the description
Please select the comments
Please select the category
Please enter the address
Please enter the city
Please enter the state
Please enter the zip

Comment: sorry this is something else, maybe you create a http://tinker.io or http://jsbin.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your answer in a fiddle which contains the same div once with errors and then without errors : http://jsfiddle.net/WhQgM/1/

Including the css for the div which will contain those errors:

```
.container{
    max-height:50px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
    width:200px;
    background-color:red;
    color:#fff;
}
```

You can adjust the color and maximum height of this div and make it according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.panel:before {
     content: attr(data);
     display:block;
     min-height: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     width:100%;
     overflow-x:scroll;  /* or overflow-y:scroll */   
}
</style>
<div class="panel"></div>
<div class="panel" data="error: hello world"></div>
```

Comment: But I need to show fixed height and an vertical scroll bar if the content is big.

Comment: again this is not so clever, because why giving output if there is no output, maybe you should arange your asp.net so that it will just "print" that message if needed. what you ask is something like a special styling if in php dump is giving some output made of errors, so it is neccessary to see the output to style it.